# How to create a file in a specific folder in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file

How can I fix the script so that the file is saved in `$PWD/source/blog`?

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'fileutils'
require 'time'

title = ARGV[0].to_s
language = ARGV[1].to_s

time = Time.new
timestamp = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
utctime = time.getutc
extension = 'html.markdown'
file = timestamp + '-' + title + '.' + language + '.' + extension
new_file = File.new(file, File::CREAT|File::TRUNC|File::RDWR, 0644)

open(file, 'a') { |f|
    f << "---\n"
    f << "title: #{title} \n"
    f << "date: #{utctime} \n"
    f << "tags:\n"
    f << "description:\n"
    f << "keywords:\n"
    f << "shorttext:\n"
    f << "---\n"
}

puts 'File created ...'
```

Comment: Files are normally created relative to the current working directory, so `source/blog/...` as a prefix should do the trick. As a note `ARGV` values are always strings unless they're `nil`.

Comment: Does `$PWD/source/blog` already exist?

Answer (score 5):

Ruby's File class has multiple ways, but probably the best for your purpose is to use [`File.join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/File.html#method-c-join). The documentation says:

> Returns a new string formed by joining the strings using File::SEPARATOR.

```
File.join("usr", "mail", "gumby")   #=> "usr/mail/gumby"
```

Doing it this way allows Ruby to auto-sense what delimiter to use between directories and the filename, based on the OS it's currently running on.

You *could* use a string with fixed delimiters, such as

```
File.join('path/to', 'file.rb')
```

or even skip using `File.join` completely and instead hard-code the path and use string interpolation:

```
"path/to/#{filename}"
```

but then the code isn't as smart. Letting Ruby do the crazy-lifting is always good.

Ruby is smart enough to automatically allow forward slashes when running on a Windows system, though Windows wants back slashes. The [IO documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/IO.html) goes into that:

> Ruby will convert pathnames between different operating system conventions if
>   possible.  For instance, on a Windows system the filename
>   "/gumby/ruby/test.rb" will be opened as "\gumby\ruby\test.rb".  When
>   specifying a Windows-style filename in a Ruby string, remember to escape the
>   backslashes:

```
"c:\\gumby\\ruby\\test.rb"
```

With all that said, in your code you could do something like:

```
File.join($PWD, 'source', 'blog')
```

I'd write your code differently, to take advantage of Ruby's features:

```
require 'time'

title, language = ARGV.values_at(0, 1)
```

It isn't necessary to use `ARGV[0].to_s` since ARGV only returns Strings. `values_at` lets us grab the values at the given indexes from `ARGV`. In more complex programs you'd want to use OptionParser, which lets you use the more standard option flags.

```
time = Time.now
timestamp = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
utctime = time.getutc
file = "#{ timestamp }-#{ title }.#{ language }.html.markdown"
```

`Time.now` is the same as `Time.new` without any parameters passed, but it's a bit more indicative of what is happening, it's returning the current time. `new` implies it's creating a new object, but doesn't hint that the default is the current time. It's a subtle thing but does help readability and maintainability.

```
File.write(
  file, 
  [
    "---\n",
    "title: #{title}",
    "date: #{utctime}",
    "tags:",
    "description:",
    "keywords:",
    "shorttext:",
    "---"
  ].join("\n")
)
```

`File.write` automatically creates and overwrites the file.

Looking at the file content you're generating, it looks like you're actually creating a YAML file, and again, Ruby can help there. Define a hash and the YAML serializer can create the proper string:

```
require 'yaml'

title = 'the_title'
utctime = 'the_utctime'

foo = {
  'title'       => title,
  'date'        => utctime,
  'tags'        => nil,
  'description' => nil,
  'keywords'    => nil,
  'shorttext'   => nil
}

puts foo.to_yaml

# >> ---
# >> title: the_title
# >> date: the_utctime
# >> tags: 
# >> description: 
# >> keywords: 
# >> shorttext:
```

---

> I don't quite see the reason, why one should use File.join here, since we don't invoke external programs. What advantage does it have if we use backslashes as path separators?

The advantage is that using backslashes limits the path to Windows only. *nix (including Mac OS) use forward-slashes. Using `File.join` lets Ruby determine which is needed depending on the current OS, so the code will work transparently wherever it's running. In the past some OSes used `:` for the path delimiter, which most people wouldn't think about. If that was encountered Ruby should continue to do the right thing.

Comment: I don't quite see the reason, why one should use `File.join` here, since we don't invoke external programs. What advantage does it have if we use backslashes as path separators?

Comment: Thank you for really nice explain the stuff. I not use yaml file, is for middleman to create new article in markdown. Only the header is yaml.

Answer (score 2):

This script creates the directory if needed :

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'fileutils'
require 'time'

title = ARGV[0].to_s
language = ARGV[1].to_s

time = Time.new
timestamp = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
utctime = time.getutc
extension = 'html.markdown'

basename = timestamp + '-' + title + '.' + language + '.' + extension
dirname = File.join(Dir.pwd, 'source', 'blog')
FileUtils.mkpath dirname unless File.exists?(dirname)
filename = File.join(dirname, basename)

# new_file = File.new(filename, File::CREAT|File::TRUNC|File::RDWR, 0644)
# NOTE: new_file wasn't used

open(filename, 'a') { |f|
    f << "---\n"
    f << "title: #{title} \n"
    f << "date: #{utctime} \n"
    f << "tags:\n"
    f << "description:\n"
    f << "keywords:\n"
    f << "shorttext:\n"
    f << "---\n"
}

puts 'File created ...'
```

Note that you didn't do anything with `new_file`.

Comment: Maybe `makedir_p` would make more sense, because it also creates the directory *source* if necessary. Also, it makes the `unless File.exists?` unnecessary.

Comment: `makedir_p` and `mkpath` are aliases, and I find mkpath more readable. You're right though, `File.exists?` is redundant. Trying to create an existing path might confuse the OP, so I added the unless expression.

Comment: Oops, I should have read more carefully: You used `mkpath`, not `mkdir`. This of course, is perfectly fine. BTW, I personally see no confusion if we try to create an existing path, but this is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

The following code create file on provide `path` directory
 where `path` is absolute path to expected directory. So, if you want to save file to `home/foo` folder then `path = '~/foo'`

```
require 'fileutils'

def create_file(path, extension)
  dir = File.dirname(path)

  unless File.directory?(dir)
    FileUtils.mkdir_p(dir)
  end

  path << ".#{extension}"
  File.new(path, 'w')
end
```